# In the help page of a function/variable, how to jump to the corresponding part in the manual?

Tags: help, manual

Sometimes the doc is just confusing without proper background knowledge mentioned in the manual (Info). How to jump to the manual from the help buffer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Place point on the symbol and press <kbd>C-h S</kbd>.
This works in buffers with `emacs-lisp-mode` and in help buffers.

Answer (score 2):

What @Tobias said.

Or if you use library [**`help-fns+.el`**](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/help-fns%2b.el) then `*Help*` buffers provide a link to help from the manuals. Option **`help-cross-reference-manuals`** in that library lets you decide the behavior:

> help-cross-reference-manuals is a variable defined in `help-fns+.el`.
>   Its value is `(("emacs" "elisp"))`
>
> Documentation:
>
> Manuals to search, for a `*Help*` buffer link to the manuals.
>   A cons.
>
> The car is a list of manuals to search, or the symbol **`all`**, to
>     search all.  If `nil`, then do not create a cross-reference link.
>
> The cdr is a boolean:
>
> - Non-`nil` means search the manuals, then create a cross-ref link:
>         create it only if some search hits are found.
> - `nil` means create a cross-ref link without searching manuals
>         first (but only if there are some manuals to search).
>
> You can customize this variable.
>
> For more information check the manuals.

The last line of that `*Help*` output is what this feature adds (to all `*Help*` buffers). The word "*manuals*" is a link (as is the word "*customize*", as usual).

The option value lets you choose whether to search manuals before displaying the `*Help*` or only when you click the `manuals` link.  The default behavior is the latter.

Answer (score 0):

If there's a link you can follow it, otherwise you just have to open the manual (`C-h i`) and navigate to the correct section yourself.